# Splitting multiple video streams and stacking them in one video output in Gstreamer

Tags: video, gstreamer

I have a setup with two RTSP cameras, from which I record two simultaneous video streams into one container file with both streams in 4K. I do this to have time synchronized between the streams. This works.

Now for what doesn't work:

I want to take these two video streams, stack them atop each other vertically and write them two an outputfile. I can do this in two separate pipelines - one that splits the streams into two separate files, which I can then feed into a stacking pipeline, but I need to do it in one.

In FFMPEG, i can accomplish this with:

```
filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[2nd][ref];[ref][2nd]vstack"
```

But for my current purposes, I want to do it with Gstreamer. The closest I can come is:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
videomixer name=mix \
sink_0::xpos=0 sink_0::ypos=0 \
sink_1::xpos=0 sink_1::ypos=2160 \
sink_2::xpos=0 sink_2::ypos=0 \
! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! mp4mux \
! filesink location=output.mp4 \
videotestsrc pattern=3 \
! "video/x-raw,format=AYUV,width=3840,height=4320,framerate=(fraction)30/1" \
! queue \
! mix.sink_0 \
filesrc location=input.mp4 \
! qtdemux name=demux \
demux.video_0 \
! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! queue ! mix.sink_1 \
demux.video_1 \
! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! queue ! mix.sink_2
```

But this only generates an empty file, and the commandline simply hangs forever. I've tried a number of different elements and combos, but nothing has really paid off. Preferably, I'd like the output to be an mp4 file, encoded in h265, but this also fails for me.

The GST_DEBUG=2 out is:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.018321312 15536 0x5645703a90c0 WARN                 basesrc     gstbasesrc.c:3480:gst_base_src_start_complete:<filesrc0> pad not activated yet
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
0:00:00.018448918 15536 0x5645703954a0 WARN                 qtdemux     qtdemux_types.c:228:qtdemux_type_get: unknown QuickTime node type pasp
0:00:00.018463999 15536 0x5645703954a0 WARN                 qtdemux qtdemux_types.c:228:qtdemux_type_get: unknown QuickTime node type pasp
0:00:00.018505858 15536 0x5645703954a0 WARN                 qtdemux qtdemux.c:3008:qtdemux_parse_trex:<demux> failed to find fragment defaults for stream 1
0:00:00.018573441 15536 0x5645703954a0 WARN                 qtdemux qtdemux.c:3008:qtdemux_parse_trex:<demux> failed to find fragment defaults for stream 2
0:00:00.018599207 15536 0x5645703954a0 WARN                 basesrc     gstbasesrc.c:2389:gst_base_src_update_length:<filesrc0> processing at or     past EOS
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
0:00:00.029453801 15536 0x564570395050 WARN             collectpads gstcollectpads.c:1411:gst_collect_pads_recalculate_waiting:<videomixer2-0-collectpads> GstCollectPads has no time segment, assuming 0 based.
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
0:00:00.172949969 15536 0x564570395000 WARN                 x264enc :0::<x264enc0> frame MB size (240x270) > level limit (36864)
0:00:00.172971144 15536 0x564570395000 WARN                 x264enc :0::<x264enc0> DPB size (4 frames, 259200 mbs) > level limit (2 frames, 184320 mbs)
Redistribute latency...
0:00:00.194095716 15536 0x564570395050 WARN               videopool     gstvideopool.c:219:video_buffer_pool_set_config:<videobufferpool6> no caps in config
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
^Chandling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
EOS on shutdown enabled -- Forcing EOS on the pipeline
Waiting for EOS...
^Chandling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
Interrupt while waiting for EOS - stopping pipeline...
Execution ended after 0:00:18.836726023
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

If left alone it will stall forever at GstSystemClock, and the file size will allways be about 150kb. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try putting queue before each demux.video_x .. in that way you move the processing of decoding of particular video stream into extra thread (this is done by queue) .. also why do you have queue before each mix.sink_n ? why dont you put one before videomixer? when you do this and it doesnt work name the queues and debug with env variable `GST_DEBUG=queue_dataflow:5 gst-launch....` in this way you will see which queue is blocked by being full or empty (if this is the case)